# Does php have a built in coversion to base32 values?

Tags: php, base32

I know I can use number_format, but is there a way to represent base32 numbers? For example, hex can be represented with 0x... and octal can be represented with a 0 in the front. Is there anything to represent base32 numbers in php?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes I meant base_convert. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the built-in function base_convert. For example:

```
// To convert from base 10 to base 32:
echo( base_convert( 12345, 10, 32 ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

I never seen a native notation for base32, but there is ofcourse [`Base_convert()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) .

Answer (score 1):

`number_format()` cannot be used to 'represent' a base 32 number, I wonder if you mean `base_convert` (http://php.net/base_convert) to move between bases, e.g.

```
echo(base_convert('FF', 16, 10));
```

As for defining them with a special prefix, as far as I'm aware PHP only supports 0 and 0x for octal/hexadecimal.