# Base64 Encoding safe for filenames?

Tags: java, hash, encoding, base64, filenames

Is Base64 encoding safe to use for filenames on Windows and Linux systems? From my research I have found that replacing all `/` characters of the result with `-` or `_` should resolve any issues.

Can anyone provide more details on this?

Currently in Java I am using the following peice of code:

```
MessageDigest md5Digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
md5Digest.reset();
md5Digest.update(plainText.getBytes());

byte[] digest = md5Digest.digest();

BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
hash = encoder.encode(digest);
hash.replace('/','_');
```

Comment: `/` seems to be a valid base64 character (No. 63) but I've never seen it in the real world: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: Note that Windows filesystems are not case sensitive. You cannot count on that a unique hash maps to a unique file.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Modified Base64 (when `/`,`=` and `+` are replaced) is safe to create names but does not guarantee reverse transformation due to case insensitivity of many file systems and urls.

Base64 is case sensitive, so it will not guarantee 1-to-1 mapping in cases of case insensitive file systems (all Windows files systems, ignoring POSIX subsystem cases). Most urls also case insensitive preventing 1-to-1 mapping.

I would use Base32 in this case - you'll get names a bit longer, but Base32 encoded values are 100% safe for file/uri usage without replacing any characters and guarantees 1-to-1 mapping even in cases of insensitive environment (FAT/Win32 NTFS access).

Unfortunately there is usually no built-in support for this encoding in frameworks. On other hand code is relatively simple to write yourself or find online.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32.

Comment: You can use base_encode function in php, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848601/does-php-have-a-built-in-coversion-to-base32-values

Comment: @Mark base_encode is only suitable for values that can be represented as numbers in PHP and the exact precision is platform-dependent, but anything over 14 decimal digits (about 9 base32 digits) may not retain integer precision, making it unsuitable for strings/hashes.

Comment: Guava supports [Base32 encoding](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html#base32()) now.

Comment: **Modified Base64 (when /,= and + are replaced) is safe to create names but does not guarantee reverse transformation due to case insensitivity of many file systems and urls.** Can you explaint it in details?

Comment: @gstackoverflow Base64 is case-sensitive, so if you care to reverse transformation back to bytes case must be preserved ("Baaa" -> "05 A6 9A", but "BAAA" => "04 00 00"). On FAT/FAT32 file name is normalized to upper case - so you can't transform file name read from file system back to byte array. Similarly often parameters of Urls are normalized (usually by misunderstanding, but still) causing the same problem. Additionally some file systems (NTFS) are case sensitive but not allow names vary just by case - so you can't construct "unique" NTFS names from distinct bytes.

Comment: url-s are actually case sensitive; on FAT/FAT32 names are also cut to 8.3, and the long filenames on FAT32 are same case-retaining as on NTFS. Also, python's standard library module `base64` does support the `base32` encoding, though maybe that wasn't he case when the answer was originally written.

Comment: @LogicDaemon thanks for adding to my point - I (mistakenly) assumed that people understand that case-preserving FS like Win32-NTFS present a problem for case-sensitive Base64 encoding (as it will drop alternatives that only differ in case), but indeed that is a tricky case that is not obvious when you test with just one non-colliding value.

Comment: @LogicDaemon if you can clarify how python library helps with Java code it would be great, also unless it is dead simple for just Base32 I'd probably would not recommend mixing languages/runtimes.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov python is not relevant, I probably just misread something and though it's about python for some reason. Please disregard the python mention.

Answer (score 13):

[RFC 3548](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3548#page-6) suggests not only to replace the `/` character. The *URL and Filename safe* Alphabet replaces:

- the 63:nd `/` character with the underscore `_`
- the 62:nd `+` character with the minus `-`.

But maybe you better use a HEX-String. It is been a while, when i stored a hash value in a filename. I started with using Base64 String but switched to a Hex-String. I don't remember why i switched, maybe because Windows makes no difference between 'a' and 'A' as AndiDog said.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure what you are using the encoding for, but consider [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) file names.

- It works in every file system
- It keeps file names human readable as long as they're within the ASCII range

Answer (score 4):

Usually MD5 hashes (hashes in general) are represented as hexadecimal strings instead of Base64, which then only contain [a-f0-9]. Those names would be supported by all filesystems.

If you really want to use Base64, your solution (replacing slashes) will not work correctly as Windows filesystems don't make a difference between 'A' and 'a'. Maybe you want to use Base32 instead? But mind that Base32 makes 8 bits out of 4, so it will be easier to just take the hexadecimal representation.

In general, the following characters are not allowed in Windows and/or Linux: \ / : * ? " < > |

Comment: In **actuality**, the only forbidden characters in Linux (and many UNIX-derivatives) are `/` and `NUL` on their native file-systems. It's usually unnecessary (and confusing) to deviate far from the more restrictive Windows set.. here is a [breakdown by filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations) (and assumes programs written correctly per target restrictions; then again, even Windows Explorer failed that test on valid FAT32 and NTFS filenames for many years..).

Answer (score 3):

One-liner for C#:

```
String filename = Convert.ToBase64String(new SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("UTF-8 string with snowmen"))).Replace("+", "_").Replace("/", "-").Replace("=","");
```

Needs the following to the beginning of the file:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography
using System.Text
```

Comment: This doesn't address the case-insensitivity problem.

Comment: And I would not call this one-liner.. Requires horizontal scroll while reading the code

Answer (score 1):

A filename created by Base64 is only safe if you use a different character from /, which you do, as NTFS does not allow that character to be used in file names. As long as you do that, pretty much [all commonly used file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems) in common use will be OK.

However, if the filesystem is *case-insensitive*, as is the case on Windows, you can get collisions because the Base64 alphabet contains both upper and lower-case.

You might want to consider using the hexadecimal representation of your MD5 hash instead, since this is a fairly standard way of representing those as a string.