# Javascript File Name Encryption and Referencing

Tags: javascript, encryption, obfuscation

I want to change the JavaScript names in my application for additional security like facebook and google plus suring deployment.

Is there are an application or a library that can change the JavaScript file names and reference them in the my view (written in php) and JavaScript files.

---

EXAMPLE OF THE DESIRED EFFECT

Change this (Before Deployment):

In folder: js/myfunction.js

In file:`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mysite.com/myfunction.js"></script>`

To this (After Deployment):

In folder: js/PuKJS78UyH.js

In file: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mysite.com/PuKJS78UyHK.js"></script>`

Comment: Don't bother. That has no effect on security, and will just make debugging harder.

Comment: I'm confused. All you're doing is renaming the folder and the js filename. How does this help security? If they could use the JS file as a test for trying to figure out your directory structure before they could still do it post-deployment.

Comment: Nobody can offer a constructive and meaningful answer until you tell us what goal you're trying to accomplish.  Obscuring or mangling script file names doesn't improve security in any way.  People can just look at what the current mangled name is in your HTML file and go fetch that file.  `PuKJS78UyHK.js` has zero difference from `myfunction.js`.  Whichever one is being used is in the HTML file and can be fetched and examined.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of obfuscating and encryption you should think about optimization. Couple things that you could do:

1. Combine all common JS files in one file (minimizes number of requests and also solves your problem - there will be no file names to obfuscate)
2. Minimize JS - it's faster that way and takes less space (and in addition it becomes unreadable)

This tool looks like a good place to start: http://code.google.com/p/minify/

Answer (score 0):

> You *should not* depend on JavaScript encryption. It is not safe, and might be hacked in a short time. Using sever side languages like PHP is much safer than JavaScript.

However, if you would like to perform a simple `base-64` encoding in JavaScript, for which normal people will not able to read, you are lucky, it doesn't need any library. `\(^o^)/`

Just use `btoa()` for encoding, and `atob()` for decoding. Then you can create a `<script>` tag using the encoded URL.

Read more in MDN: [***`window.atob`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.atob)

**Example:**

```
var txt = "myfunction.js";
var encode = btoa(txt);
var decode = atob(encode);
console.log( encode );  //return "bXlmdW5jdGlvbi5qcw=="
console.log( decode );  //return "myfunction.js" (orginal)

//Do whatever you want with the encoded text, like
$("<script src='/js/"+encode+".js' type='text/javascript'></script>")
    .appendTo("head");  //dynamically adding an script tag using jQuery
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/JWSUs/

Result:
[image: result]

> Result from jsFiddle. You can see that "myfunction.js" is encoded to "bXlmdW5jdGlvbi5qcw==", which normal people will not be able to read.

Comment: "which normal people will not be able to read." - normal people will not read your source code in the first place, and not normal people will be able to smell base-64 from across the room ;)

Comment: Because what you suggesting is bad practice. Your solution will only clutter the main file with something that doesn't do anything and therefore doesn't need to be in the code. Also base64 was created to represent binary data in ascii, not to encode file names. There are plenty of tools which can replace references to files during deployment without any overhead. That's what google, fb and all the big boys does.

Comment: I already stated that it should use sever side language for this kind of stuff, in the the beginning.

Comment: Not arguing with that. Just saying that it's misleading to say that base64 could be used for encoding file names. It can contain "/" and can cause collisions in non-case-sensitive file systems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945541/base64-encoding-safe-for-filenames. And in addition to that your example writes decoded file names to DOM, which defeats the purpose of it - anyone looking at the document using inspector would see decoded file names.

Comment: Yea I agree with your point too, but I was just saying that he could use `base64` for basic encoding purposes.