# Convert LARGE_INTEGER to base 64 string

Tags: c++

I am using `QueryPerformanceCounter();` to get a number for use as a unique timestamp to be included in a filename.

```
LARGE_INTEGER performanceCount;
QueryPerformanceCounter(&performanceCount);
```

I need to encode `performanceCount.HighPart` which is of type `LONG` and `performanceCount.LowPart` which is of type `DWORD` as base64 strings. Then concatenate them and store them in a `wstring` variable.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I’d question whether that’s really a good solution. The number will be huge. Why not use a simple consecutive counter instead or, lacking that, a GUID?

Comment: Which part of the task are you having trouble with? Base64 conversion is a solved problem. Any search will find you many implementations. String concatenation is also well understood, such that the language has it built in.

Comment: The proposed approach of converting the two numbers separately is fine but not "perfect" (5-bit/symbol output doesn't map to 64+32 input bits); although converting a "byte array" is probably easier to find implementations for. What has been tried in that aspect?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Standard GUID implementations do not have an ordering and a consecutive counter requires some atomic lock/central provider. A performance counter "should" have a low chance of collision while having some sense of order. (Of course there are other - perhaps more appropriate - approaches like Snowflake used in Twitter.)

Comment: There are some issues using base64 in filenames http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945541/base64-encoding-safe-for-filenames

Comment: You would be better off hex-encoding the bytes if a file-name is the ultimate purpose (not to mention, look how -pretty- the filenames line up in an explorer pane =P) would that be acceptable?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, thanks for the suggestion but a counter isn't really suitable and the filenames need to be ordered so GUIDs aren't really ideal either.

Comment: @pst Thanks for the suggestion. I might try this although in light of Martin's point I might try with base32.

Comment: @MartinBeckett Thanks for your point it's good to be aware of.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you for your suggestion this would be excellent. Is there a C++ function that does this?

Comment: Not really, but it is braindead simple to implement. Give me a minute and i'll see if I can post one for you. you just walk the high DWORD, then low DWORD, hibyte to lobyte each, xlating byte to 0x00-0xFF form. when done you should have a name 32 chars wide. does that make sense ?

Comment: @WhozCraig I understand the principle but am a little unsure/unconfident of how to implement it well. Also C++ is new to me, I have previously done a little C#. Types seem more fundamental in C++ and I'm not at all familiar with the C++ libraries and headers. By walking the DWORD do you mean getting a pointer to the start of the DWORD and incrementing it to access each byte? If you could show me how to do it properly that would be very helpful!

Comment: I'll post up something that creates a std::string. hopefully that will be ok for what you need.

Comment: Thanks that would be super!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid problems with using base64-chars with filename [(see this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945541/base64-encoding-safe-for-filenames), You would likely be better served using base16's limited character set. Even in 32-bit compilation, MS still supports the QuadPart member of [LARGE_INTEGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383713%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so we''re using it.

**EDIT**: per suggestion for comments, primary way of doing this should be using string streams:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::wstring LargeIntToString(const LARGE_INTEGER& li)
{
    std::wstringstream wss;
    wss << hex << setw(16) << setfill(L'0') << li.QuadPart;
    return wss.str();
}


int main()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);

    wcout << LargeIntToString(li) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output** (at the time I ran it on my machine, anyway)

```
00000041f40cdd33
```

Comment: Just realize you wanted `wstring`. no problem. one more edit.

Comment: He requests base64 rather than Hex.  If you used hex rather than base64 on purpose, please explain why in the answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for the example Craig! It's really useful to see a practical use of bit shift operators as well.

Comment: @MooingDuck Until he seemed to agree with the problems of base64 in filenames, specifically in response to [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594052/convert-large-integer-to-base-64-string#comment18634401_13594052) regarding [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945541/base64-encoding-safe-for-filenames) which is what brought us to base16. I thought the comments covered it, but if you think it appropriate to link in the answer as well, I certainly will.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Since comments can be and are deleted without warning, I think it's appropriate to link to the question.

Comment: @MooingDuck I think its totally related, actually, and is the "why can't I think of the easy way to do this with the std lib" I mentioned earlier. A combination of manipulators `hex`, `setw` and `setfill` would make this a lot more robust, I concur. When I edit this to include the link I'll likely throw that in as another way to do it. You're absolutely correct.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Edited my stringstream code to use setw and setfill.  Use at will.

Comment: @MooingDuck and the irony is, i didn't even see you're comment has a link until I checked my comment popup after updating the post. Apart from the param to the func and the order of the manips, its *identical*. lol. Thanks for kicking me in the right direction, sir.

Comment: @MooingDuck Thank you for the alternative technique! It seems more succinct and simpler so I think it is the one I shall finally use. However seeing Craig's example with bitshift and bitwize operators has been very useful.

Comment: @FunkyFresh84 Absolutely. Using string streams was how I would have done it in the first place had I not been suffering from total brain-lock (long day at work). It is easily the simplest way to do it.